# how to check if the input 42 to length long and must have 0x at the beginning

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

I need the input to be 42 to length long and must have 0x at the beginning like **0x**collaboratingcorerivnefvting so how can i achieve that using jquery

```html
<html lang="en-US" class="lang-en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text"   id="check" data-minlength="42" name="address" onKeyDown="javascript: var keycode = keyPressed(event); if(keycode==32){ return false; }" />

    <button class="button button-rounded-rectangle" type="button" id="kato" disabled>Continue</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $(function () {
        $("#kato").prop("disabled", true);
      
        $("#check").on("input", function (e) {
          if (this.value.length === 42) {
            $("#kato").prop("disabled", false);
           
          } 

          else {
            $("#kato").prop("disabled", true);
            
          }
        });
      });
      //]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Split'n'Pop `else if (this.value.split('.').pop() === 'io') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions. You can find useful info about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Ready code is below. If I didn't get your question right, feel free to point at that. All the best!

```html
<html lang="en-US" class="lang-en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="check" data-minlength="42" name="address" onKeyDown="onInputKeyDown" />
        <button class="button button-rounded-rectangle" type="button" id="kato" disabled>Continue</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onInputKeyDown() {
                var keycode = keyPressed(event);
                if(keycode == 32) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //<![CDATA[
            $(function () {
                $("#kato").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#check").on("input", function (e) {
                    var regexpr = /^0x[a-z0-9]*$/;
                    if (regexpr.test(this.value) && this.value.length === 42) {
                        $("#kato").prop("disabled", false);
                    } else {
                        $("#kato").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                });
            });
        //]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer was a little wrong. Thank you for drawing my attention to this, Art Bindu!

Answer (score 0):

If you want validate a string with `0x` then use regex= `/^0x[0-9a-f]+/gi` (i: for ignoring case for hexadecimal code). Validate with `regex.test(inputString)`

If you want to check the length of hexadecimal code exactly 42 lengths (including the length of `0x`): then use regex= `/^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/gi`.

```
/^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/gi.test('0x1234567891113151719212325272931333537a42') // true
/^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/gi.test('0x1234567891113151719212325272931333537a42a') // false
/^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/gi.test('0x1234567891113151719212325272931333537$42') // false
/^0x[0-9a-f]{40}$/gi.test('0x1234567891113151719212325272931333537a4')// false
```

Here you may test the string start with `0x` along with length.